# need help with sorting an array

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following array

```
1.0000    2.0000    0.4231
1.0000    3.0000    0.8050
1.0000    4.0000    0.7116
2.0000    4.0000    0.6682
2.0000    5.0000    0.4460
2.0000    7.0000    0.5818
3.0000    4.0000    0.0977
3.0000    6.0000    0.5989
3.0000    7.0000    0.3237
4.0000    7.0000    0.2882
5.0000    6.0000    0.1456
5.0000    7.0000    0.3168
6.0000    7.0000    0.2767
```

I want to sort rows according to the elements of column 3 in a descending order.
So that the sorted array is like:

1.0000    3.0000    0.8050

1.0000    4.0000    0.7116

2.0000    4.0000    0.6682

3.0000    6.0000    0.5989

.......................................

.......................................

Note that, if I use 'sortrows' then the array is sorted in a ascending order automatically which I could not change. If I use 'sort', each column is sorted individually which is not what I want. Any help would be highly appreciated.

-Faisal

Comment: How is this array stored? 
You could create a table out of it then using a data view you would be able to sort by any column you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort in descending order you need a negative column index.

```
sortrows(a, -3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the next page of the manual:

> sortrows(X,COL) sorts the matrix based
>   on the columns specified in the
>       vector COL.

especially the next sentence after the one I have quoted.

Comment: Would vote up except why don't you just post "the next sentence".

Comment: @Dustin: because I grew tired of cutting and pasting text from the Matlab on-line help.  I'm not proud of it, but it was all the strength I could muster at the time.

Answer (score -1):

sortrows(yourArray,3)